# CMake: Hide -WShadow global compile flag for child target

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, protocol-buffers

Background:
I have `-WShadow` compile flag set for all sub targets (many modules present in my project).

Now, I'm adding a third-party library (Google's protobuf which has shadowed code in some places) into project tree. This third party library will be **cmake** sub target under parent project. As this library has shadowed code in some places, global `-WShadow` flag causes compile error when I tried to build.

Question:
Is there any way I can hide `-WShadow` flag for protobuf target? 
I don't find any no shadow flag which I can set for protobuf target's compile options.

Comment: `I don't find any no shadow flag which I can set for protobuf target's compile options.` - According to [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), it implies that for every `-W..` option there is an `-Wno-...` pair, which has reverse effect. Or do you ask about where should you add `-Wno-shadow` flag?

Answer (score 2):

When including thirdparty projects into your `cmake` build, it's helpful to use [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/ExternalProject.html) instead of just dumping their source tree into your own and `add_subdirectory`-ing it. ExternalProject will recursively invoke cmake and build the thirdparty project in its own scope. You can explicitly propagate flags to it as you wish, but it avoids the scenario you currently have where things in scope for your own build "leak" into the thirdparty build system and cause undesired behaviour.

The section [here](https://mirkokiefer.com/cmake-by-example-f95eb47d45b1) about using external libraries provides a reasonable example.

Another option to consider is using `find_package` instead of compiling Protobuf yourself. That's almost always less hassle.

Another option would be to add the flags to your own targets using `target_compile_options()` instead of the global `compile_options()`, thius avoiding leaking them into the default flag list. This is somewhat brittle, however.

Comment: I *guess* the asker have put `-Wshadow` flag into *CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS* variable (I find this variable the proper place for such *check-my-code* flags). And while even `compile_options` command is scoped (one may issue it in a subdirectory), `CMAKE_*_FLAGS` variables are always global. I agree that `ExternalProject` is a proper way for such cases. But as you have described difference between `compile_options` and `target_compile_options`, description of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable could be also useful.